# Nominals, prices, utility

Tags: actuarial-science, utility

An investor is considering two possible assets, a three month one A with a yield of $4\%$ convertible quarterly and some three month one B.

a) For a nominal of 100, determine the price of A.

b) The investor believes that A is risk-free but that B has a probability of default $2.5\%$ and a loss given default of $100%$. The utility function is $u(w) = \sqrt{w}$. The initial wealth is $100$ and is to be fully invested so that the expected utility three months from now is maximized. 
Denote the price for 100 nominal of B by $P_B$. For which values of $P_B$ the investor would choose to invest:

i) Everything in A
ii) Half in A, half in B
iii) Everything in B

---

My approach - I am just asking if I have started correctly, as there are some new terms for me.

a) If the price is $P$ then we denote $i^{(4)} = 4\%$ and have $100 - P(1+i)^{-1} = 0$ where $1+i = (1+\frac{i^{(4)}}{4})^4$ from which $P = 104.060401$ 
(My concern here is whether it is $100 - P(1+i)^{-1} = 0$ or $100 - P(1+i) = 0$ as I am not completely sure what is meant)

b) If we invest $\alpha$ in $A$ and $100 - \alpha$ in $B$, then the realized wealth is $\alpha(1+i) + (100 - \alpha)X$ where $1+i$ is as in a) and $X = 0$ with probability $0.025$ and $P_B/100$ with probability $0.975$. The expected utility is $0.975\sqrt{\alpha(1+i) + (100 - \alpha)P_B/100} + 0.025\sqrt{\alpha(1+i)}$ and we wish to see for which $P_B$ this maximized at $\alpha  = 100, 50, 0$.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Note:  you provide no information about asset $B$.  All you say is "some three month one B".  Also, you say that $A$ is convertible but you don't say what the terms of the conversion are (nor even what $A$ is convertible into).

Comment: B is such that "the price for 100 nominal of B is P_B". What do you mean by "what the terms of conversion are and what is A convertible into"? For "convertible into", it should be "invest and then get money from it" or?

Comment: Many assets are priced at par.  You need to specify what return characteristics $B$ has.  As to the other...what do you think "convertible" means?  Usually the term is used to describe debt instruments that can, at the investor's option, be converted into equity.  But I think you are using the word in some nonstandard way.

Comment: Your question is missing a lot of details.  For instance, it is not possible to price a fixed rate bond $A$ (now I'm assuming you used "convertible" without understanding what it meant) without knowing the risk free rate.  Please edit your post to include all the necessary information.

Comment: I can't edit it :( I have copied the formulation from the past exam paper. Hence there is no better way for me to express it.

Comment: Well, as there's not enough information here to answer the question, I'm voting to close it.

Comment: The price of bond B implies an interest rate if it is using arbitrage free pricing. We have to find the price at which the expected utily of B beats A and vice versa.

Comment: More details, please?